# JAWR minified JS files having sytax error in IE versions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring, jawr

We are using an AngularJS application with a java spring backend APIs, all the client side stuff code JS, CSS etc are being minified by jawr 3.9. Application is working with chrome and firefox however it is saying a syntax error with IE11

Error details:

> SCRIPT5022: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
>   Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: possibly using some ES2015+ syntax that IE11 doesn't and never will understand ... who can say without code

Comment: can you post your scripts and their order?

Comment: @JaromandaX, is this a ES2015+ code?

`$scope.subBitMappings.findIndex(subBitMapping=>subBitMapping.code==result.code.code);`

Comment: it's best to not use the arrow notation, so you can change it to `$scope.subBitMappings.findIndex(function(subBitMapping) { return subBitMapping.code == result.code.code});`

Comment: yes, it is, IE11 has no idea what `=>` is